# Simplifying an expression involving a matrix and functions of it

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra, assumptions, eigenvalues

I have implemented the following two matrices in Mathematica in order to compute `s,` but I don't know how I can further simplify the resulting expressions, e.g., Mathematica seems to not perform the trace in the denominator for `s.` Applying `Simplify` with the assumption that the $3$ variables are positive does not seem to matter much. Below is my attempt:

---

```
Q = {{x^2, 0., 0.}, {0., y^2, 0.}, {0., 0., z^2}};
Qhat = Table[
   Part[Q, i, j] - KroneckerDelta[i, j]*Tr[Q/3], {i, 3}, {j, 3}] // 
  MatrixForm
s = (4*Det[Qhat])/(2/3. *(Tr[Qhat^2]))^(3/2)
Simplify[s, x^2 > 0 && y^2 > 0 && z^2 > 0]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Don't use `MatrixForm` to define matrices. It is only a display wrapper and interferes with evaluation.

Comment: @Roman Ah nice spot! that has already made a huge difference, now it evaluates `s` normally, thanks! Please feel free to post as an answer so I can accept, may be useful for future readers, and in case you also wanted to add something about the simplification.

Comment: @Roman you should be able to get around that (albeit not producing cleaner or more efficient code) with an Evaluate[] wrapper, yeah? If I am mostly understanding most things, anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `MatrixForm` to define matrices. It is only a display wrapper and interferes with evaluation. See, for example, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/26598